# HTML/CSS webpage not looking as it should

Tags: html, css, user-interface

1) My nav and aside are not high enough. They dont begin where they should nor they end when they should.

2) My section (and nav and aside) don't end in the bottom of the page.

3) My footer is not in the bottom of the page.

I am using HTML and CSS. I am currently using Google Chrome.

**I want my page looks like this:**

[image]

**And it looks like this:**
[image]

**HTTP:**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Titulazo</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">   

</head>

<body>      
    <header id = "MainHeader">
        <h1>Main Header h1</h1>
        <p>Hello world! This is HTML5 Boilerplate.</p>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <h1>Nav h1</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>bla</li>
            <li>bla</li>
            <li>bla</li>            
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section>
        <h1>Section h1</h1>
        <header>
            <h1>Section header</h1>
        </header>   

        <article>
            <h1>Article h1</h1>
            <p>Posted on <time datetime="2009-10-22">October 22, 2009</time></p>
            <p>Article text</p>
        </article>

        <footer>
            <h1>Section Footer</h1>
        </footer>
    </section>

    <aside>
        <h1>Aside h1</h1>
        <p>Aside text</p>       
    </aside>

    <footer id = "MainFooter">
        <h1>Main Footer, copyright 2018, Álvaro Puertas</h1>
    </footer>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-Y to be your site's ID. -->
    <script>
    window.ga = function () { ga.q.push(arguments) }; ga.q = []; ga.l = +new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto'); ga('send', 'pageview')
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    height:auto; 
}

header#MainHeader{  
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 20px;        
 } 

nav { 
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: auto;  
  width:200px;
  margin: 20px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  bottom: 0px;
}

section{
    width: 900px;
    height: auto; 
    float: left;    
    top: 500px;
    background-color: pink; 
}

aside{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    top: 0px;
    float: right;
    background-color: lightgreen;   
}

footer#MainFooter{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;   
    background-color: gray;

    margin: 20px;   
    clear:both; 
}
```

Comment: read responsive design tutorial or use css framework

Answer (score 0):

> 1) My nav and aside are not high enough. They dont begin where they
>   should nor they end when they should.

- Add height:100% to body,nav and aside; remove position: absolute from body; also remove position: relative from nav, section and aside because they are positioned using floats, better use margins to position them than position relative / absolute. Remove/replace margin:20px (with margin: 0 20px) for nav and aside to make them to start from same vertical position

> 2) My section (and nav and aside) don't end in the bottom of the page.

- Don't forget to clear the floated nav, section and aside.

> 3) My footer is not in the bottom of the page.

- Add height: 100% to the html tag and position the footer absolute or fixed, depending on the requirements with bottom: 0, pay attention what happens to nav, section and aside when the overflow footer's area.

Answer (score 0):

try adding following css: final output :[image: Click Here]

```
body{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    height:auto; 
    margin: 0;
}

/*mycode*/
header p{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


header#MainHeader{  
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 20px;        
 } 

nav { 
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 75vh;  
  width:15%;
  margin: 0 20 10px 20px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  bottom: 0px;
}

section{
    width: 64%;
    min-height: 75vh; 
    float: left;    
    top: 500px;
    background-color: pink; 
}

aside{
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 75vh;
    margin: 0 20 10px 20px;
    top: 0px;
    float: right;
    background-color: lightgreen;   
}

footer#MainFooter{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;   
    background-color: gray;

    margin: 20px;   
    clear:both; 
}
```

this is not the best was to do it. I would suggest you to learn bootstrap grid layout and also learn to use chrome developer tools.

Answer (score -1):

You should fix the footer position by adding:

```
position:fixed;
left:0px;
bottom:0px;
```

To the footer's CSS

For your nav and aside, you should remove the position: absolute from body and change nav's height to 100%

Comment: Giving the footer a `fixed` position will make it sticky. I wouldn't assume that that is the desired behavior without OP specifying as such.